# Laravel - artisan Ругается почему - то

Tags: php, laravel

запускаю так

php artisan serve

Вот что мне выдает

```
[InvalidArgumentException]       
  Attribute [ant] does not exist.
```

Гуглил, не наткнулся на решение.

Answer (score 1):

Решение было в том что, прописал в routes контроллер преждем чем создать сам контроллер.